# How to server side render individual components in react?

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, spring-boot, server-side-rendering

I have a react application with spring backend. I want to server side render a specific component.
My react application runs on port 3000 and spring application on port 8080. How can I just put one component on spring rather than an entire route?

Answer (score 0):

You haven't shared a lot about your setup regarding frontend nor how it does it communicate with the backend service so it's hard to give a precise answer.

First of all, ensure you already have  server side rendering (SSR) engine up and running. This will not be the case if you are using something like create-react-app which works only client-side.

If you have SSR setup, please have a closer look at `ReactDOM.renderToString/renderToNodeStream/renderToStaticMarkup` (depending on which one is used). There you can add your logic how to decide which part of component's tree is rendered.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ThymeLeaf / Moustache for SSR but if you're specific only to React SSR then you'll need an Express.JS based server returning SSR HTML in response to the request made by the client.